# All sorts of errors running Robolectric tests: Theme.AppCompat, NoClassDefFoundError and more

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

My Android project has about ~70 Robolectric tests and they were all passing for 2 months. Somehow, starting today, the tests are failing with weird error messages:

- java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
- Also can't load resource files

I didn't change my code, so it can't be code related issue. I cleaned project and gradle but it didn't help. I did do a update promoted by Android Studio a few days ago, not sure if related.

Is anyone else is experiencing the issue? How do I get out of this bad state?

-- edit --

Robolectric version matters! Interesting observation based on suggestions in comments, robolectric version v.s. failure rate:

- 3.3.1, ~40% of the tests fail.
- 3.2.2, ~40% failure (same as 3.3.1)
- 3.1.4, ~15% failure
- 3.1.2, ~0% failure (with caveats, see below)
- 3.1, 100% failure (!)

Another observation is that it's inconsistent. If I run the whole set, all pass! But If I only run one test file, all fail with this message:

> No such manifest file:
>   build/intermediates/bundles/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Which version of Robolectric are you using?

Comment: It is working fine here on Robolectric 3.0 . Did you try doing 'Invalidate caches / restart' ? And did you try running it with gradlew on command line: `gradlew clean testDebug` ?

Comment: Thanks guys the comments helped. I was trying different versions. Please see my updates.

Comment: Can you show an example of your test setup? If you run it from the command line do they succeed?

Comment: If I do "./gradlew test", it works; but then it's no difference from running all at once from AS, which works too. Not sure what my test setup is, just the AS' default, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

AS is quite sensitive about dependencies change, as well AS doesn't set the working directory for tests by default.

`No such manifest ...` error directly saying that **Robolectric** can not find your manifest.

Whenever you have test failing in AS check first the command line run if it is reproducible.

Check first working directory for test:
[image: screenshot for working directory settings]

I would also recommend to setup module directory as working directory by default:
[image: screenshot for default working directory]